# How to make the unsubscribe link in Outlook work for newsletters?

Tags: email, outlook, html-email, newsletter

We send out email newsletters and automated confirmation emails to users of our websites. Each email has an unsubscribe link in the email footer and each recipient opted in to receive emails.

Outlook webmail has the unsubscribe link above the body of the email in the following form:

> Getting too much email from #SENDER#? You can unsubscribe

Clicking on the link opens a dialog window with following content:

> Block this sender
>
> [SENDER] hasn't given us any information to help you unsubscribe, so we'll block everything sent from the following sender: [EMAIL_ADDRESS]
>
> [×] Also delete everything from [SENDER] in my Inbox folder

I search the internet and even contacted the Outlook support and asked them what info they need from us to help recepients unsubscribe from our emails. After several email exchanges the Outlook support concluded that they have no idea how to change Outlook's unsubscribe link, what information we should give them and how we should give them the information.

Can anyone please advise or point me to the right direction please? Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to mention that we are registered with Outlook's Smart Network Data Service. The complaint rate is <0.1% which is healthy.

Answer (score 0):

Is it "List-Unsubscribe" MIME header? http://www.list-unsubscribe.com/

Comment: Possibly. The email header includes the following: 
List-Unsubscribe: http://www.domain.com/unsubscribe/

Looking at it now, we should add the angle brackets to it:
List-Unsubscribe: <http://www.domain.com/unsubscribe/>

We'll test it to see if it helps. Thank you.

Comment: I corrected the list-unsubscribe link but it didn't make any difference. Still getting the same dialogue window in Outlook. :(

Comment: I added an email address to the List-Unsubscribe header (along with the URL) and now the message in the dialogue window is different:
`We will ask [SENDER] to take you off their mailing list. If they send anything in the meantime, we'll put it in junk.`
So we will have to manually unsubscribe Outlook users AND we won't even be able to let them know that we've done so.
I think we are one step closer from banning users with Outlook, Live, MSN and Hotmail email addresses from registering with us. Email communication is vital for our websites.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing a couple of things here. First, while outlook.com is a Microsoft domain, Outlook itself is an entirely different thing, and people can be using Outlook as their mail program regardless of what domain they have. You won't know what client people are using for email, or what server they use to access it. Second, you say that email communication is vital for your websites. Banning people from your newsletters doesn't help that situation in the least. People using the various Microsoft services that you mention have no trouble receiving and participating in those email communications. What you don't touch on, is what software you're using for your newsletters. THAT is where your problem probably is. If you go to that domain.com/unsubscribe URL, what does that page do/look like? There are 2 usual links for a List-Unsubscribe header. One is a mailto: link such as unsub-list-12345@domain.com, where any email to that address performs an unsubscription. For the web link version, it needs to be a link to a page that automatically unsubscribes the user (so the link would need to be customized with variables such as the mailing list).

Comment: I understand your pooint re. various domains being used with Outlook. We started deleting accounts for users who click on the unsubscribe link but this only resulted in confusion and frustration of users who don't realise that by unsubscribing their accounts get deleted. Not much we can do about it I guess.